# Convert a curve to a mesh with a user defined resolution

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I know there is a setting that controls the curve resolution but it seems you can't set some precise value to get, say, a mesh replica with exactly 15 verts for example. Is there any addon capable of doing so if Blender can't do that out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bezier Curves**

The curve resolution is already an exact parameter that drives the resolution of the surface (for example in U direction), but it is taking into account the number of **faces**, not vertices.

For a curve without V resolution (0), the faces collapse into edges, so you'll have a starting vertex, than an edge(1) followed by a vertex (1), than an edge(2) followed by a vertex (2), ... than an edge(n) followed by a vertex (n).

At the end the number of vertices is always n+1, with n as the number of edges/faces resulting from the moltiplication of the resolution and the number of segments of your spline.

The following example consider a spline made of 1 segment (2 control points). See how in this case the resolution is equal to the number of resulting edges.

[image]

The final formula should be:

> n° of final vertices = n° spline segments * resolution + 1

**Nurbs Curves**

Nurbs have a different mathematical implementation from Beziers.

They require at least 3 control points to build a proper geometry. If you set the Resolution parameter to 1, you can see how the number of edges constituting the figure is equal to the number of control edges minus 1. But as the number of final vertices is equal to the number of final edges plus one (as seen before), we can say that the numberof final vertices is equal to the number of control edges that the Nurbs has.

So for example a Nurbs curve made with 5 control edges, will result in a curve with 5 vertices once converted to mesh, if the resolution is set to 1.

As the tooltip says, the *Resolution* Parameter controls the number of subdivision per segment. Here's a few result for the previous example:

- Res: 1 -> 5 vertex (4 edges)
- Res: 2 -> 5*2 = 10 vertex (9 edges)
- Res: 3 -> 5*3 = 15 vertex (14 edges)
- Res: 4 -> 5*4 = 20 vertex (19 edges)
- ....
- Res: n -> 5*n vertex (5*n-1 edges)

The final formula should be:

> n° of final vertices = n° of control edges * resolution

Comment: Thanks for the explanation though it gets a bit more complicated once you start messing with the Nurbs curves as the resolution parameter in this case isn't as straightforward as in your example.

Comment: I didn't realize you were talking about Nurbs Curves, what I said is true for Curve object only. I'll have a look, but I think there should be a rule for them also

Comment: Now I see the difference. Thanks for taking the time to explain this concept in great detail. Thumbs up and highly appreciated!